# Material Angular, how to add an attribute to a md-text-float directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, material-design

I use material.angular for my user formular, the input "name" is like that :

```
<md-text-float label="Username" ng-model="userEdit.user.nickname"></md-text-float>
```

And I want to add the "required" attribute to the input previously created, but it seems to be hard, material allow me to specify a type or the "disabled" attr but nothing else.

Can I add an attribute after the creation of the field ?

Comment: FYI, `md-text-float` has been deprecated in favor of a `md-input-container` approach. Details here: https://github.com/angular/material/blob/v1.0.6/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-19

Answer (score 2):

You can now use the 'required' attribute on `<md-text-float>` element,

It's working on version v0.6.1-master-fc723d4

If you need other attributes to pass along to your `<input>` element, you could use the following:

```
<md-input-group class="md-default-theme">
   <label for="">something </label>
   <md-input  ng-model="myValue" ng-change="doSomethingOnChange()"  ng-blur="doSomethingOnBlur()" autocapitalize="off" type=""></md-input>
</md-input-group>
```

a working **[codepen](http://codepen.io/nbaleli/pen/JoXPVZ)**

see this **[discussion](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/547#issuecomment-65620808)** on github

Answer (score 0):

Until this issue is fixed, you can add attributes using the `link` function inside your own directive.

Assuming you created a directive `myDirective`, with a template that contains the `md-text-float` element, you can then do the following:

```js
angular.module ('myModule', [])
  .directive ('myDirective', function () {
    return {
      // your own directive parameters
      // ...
      
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.find ('input').attr ('required', 'true');
      }
    };
  });
```